# JMSerializer exclude entity by property condition

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I have a symfony application with JMSSerializerBundle installed.
My Entity looks like this:

```
class MyEntity {

    /**
     * Attribute[]
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Attribute", mappedBy="myEntity")
     * @JMS\Groups({"attributeSet_detail"})
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"position" = "ASC"})
     */
    protected $attributes;
}
```

The `AppBundle\Entity\Attribute` Entity has a boolean property `isActive`

Now I want to serialize the `MyEntity` (including all `attributes`) BUT only those which property `isActive` is set to `true`

Answer (score 3):

You can use JMS Serializer Dynamic exclusion strategy.

```
<?php

class MyObject
{

    /**
     * @Exclude(if="true")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @Expose(if="true")
     */
    private $name2;
}
```

Have a look at the documentation here: https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies

Comment: No, sorry. That is useful if I want to exclude a single property, but it doesn't work to exclude a whole object.